# can't upload file on server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying use this example http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/example2.html for recording audio and send it to my localhost server, but I have issue here. My code describe below

```
<script>

   $.jRecorder(

     { 
        host : 'http://localhost/Jrec/html/acceptfile.php?filename=hello.wav',  
        callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started(); },
        callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
        callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
        callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },
        callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending() },
        swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',

     }
   );
   </script>
```

this my acceptfile.php

```
      if(!isset($_REQUEST['filename']))
   {
     exit('No file');
   }

   $upload_path = dirname(__FILE__). '/';

   $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

   $fp = fopen($upload_path."/".$filename.".wav", "wb");

   fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));

   fclose($fp);

   exit('done');
```

whalt should I do with $upload_path = dirname(**FILE**). '/;?
when I press send data button the file doesn't upload into following directory ("files"). What is the problem here, Any help will be apriciated

Comment: Why are you using an absolute path? Isn't it on the same domain? Plus, can you give us some logs ?

Comment: FYI, you have an extra trailing comma after "swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works like *Shikiryu* and *seth flowers* said. But remember to remove .wav from filename because it adds the extension .wav here:
    `$fp = fopen($upload_path."/".$filename.".wav", "wb");`

Answer (score 0):

Also note the 2 forward-slashes "/" concatenated in the filepath variable `$fp`.

- 1st from `$upload_path`
- 2nd from `$fp`

This assumes you will create a folder in your directory to store the sound file.

`$fp = fopen($upload_path."NAME_OF_FOLDER/".$filename.".wav", "wb");`